# BF#: Round 2 (Fight!)

Tags: c#, interpreter, brainfuck, compiler

So I've completely changed how BrainfuckSharp does things, and added some features. This is obviously a follow up to: [Interpreting Brainfuck code to C#, then compiling to a .exe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107713/interpreting-brainfuck-code-to-c-then-compiling-to-a-exe)

It now features an `OptimizationLevel` (currently hardcoded, will fix for the future) that allows you to indicate how far you want the interpreted code optimized. The `OptimizationLevel.Level1` level will smash subsequent calls to the increment/decrement and move left/right tokens together into one call. (Instead of `>>` turning into `index++; index++;` it now turns into `index += 2;`.)

Just as well, it's now much more like a "true" compiler in that it treats everything like a token.

Let's start with the `TokenSymbol` enum:

```
public enum TokenSymbol
{
    None,
    MoveLeft,
    MoveRight,
    LoopBegin,
    LoopEnd,
    Increment,
    Decrement,
    OutputValue,
    InputCharacter
}
```

This represents every possible token in Brainfuck, and a default "None" token.

Next, `OptimizationLevel`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines how the <see cref="Interpreter"/> will optimize Brainfuck code.
/// </summary>
public enum OptimizationLevel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Do not apply any optimizations.
    /// </summary>
    None,
    /// <summary>
    /// Apply first level optimizations (combining sequences of increment/decrement characters into one increment/decrement per sequence).
    /// </summary>
    Level1,
}
```

This is self-explanatory. It represents the (currently two) possible optimization levels of BrainfuckSharp. Specifying `None` will not optimize the code, specifying `Level1` will apply basic optimizations.

On to the `Interpreter`:

```
public class Interpreter
{
    public OptimizationLevel OptimizationLevel { get; set; } = OptimizationLevel.None;

    public List<string> Lines { get; } = new List<string>();

    private List<TokenSymbol> _symbols = new List<TokenSymbol>();
    private List<char> _validTokens = new List<char> { '<', '>', ',', '.', '+', '-', '[', ']' };
    private Dictionary<char, TokenSymbol> _tokenMap = new Dictionary<char, TokenSymbol>
    {
        { '<', TokenSymbol.MoveLeft },
        { '>', TokenSymbol.MoveRight },
        { ',', TokenSymbol.InputCharacter },
        { '.', TokenSymbol.OutputValue },
        { '[', TokenSymbol.LoopBegin },
        { ']', TokenSymbol.LoopEnd },
        { '+', TokenSymbol.Increment },
        { '-', TokenSymbol.Decrement }
    };

    private void Tokenize(string brainfuck)
    {
        foreach (char c in brainfuck)
        {
            if (_validTokens.Contains(c))
            {
                _symbols.Add(_tokenMap[c]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteToFile(string filename)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            foreach (string line in Lines)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Interpret(string brainfuck)
    {
        Tokenize(brainfuck);

        var lastSymbol = TokenSymbol.None;
        var symbolRepeated = 0;
        var indents = 3;

        foreach (var symbol in _symbols)
        {
            switch (symbol)
            {
                case TokenSymbol.LoopBegin:
                    if ((OptimizationLevel & OptimizationLevel.Level1) >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
                    {
                        if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
                        {
                            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                            symbolRepeated = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lastSymbol = symbol;
                            symbolRepeated++;
                        }
                    }

                    symbolRepeated = 0;
                    Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                    indents += 1;
                    break;
                case TokenSymbol.LoopEnd:
                    if ((OptimizationLevel & OptimizationLevel.Level1) >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
                    {
                        if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
                        {
                            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                            symbolRepeated = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lastSymbol = symbol;
                            symbolRepeated++;
                        }
                    }

                    indents -= 1;
                    symbolRepeated = 0;
                    Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                    break;
                case TokenSymbol.InputCharacter:
                    if ((OptimizationLevel & OptimizationLevel.Level1) >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
                    {
                        if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
                        {
                            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                            symbolRepeated = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lastSymbol = symbol;
                            symbolRepeated++;
                        }
                    }

                    symbolRepeated = 0;
                    Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                    break;
                case TokenSymbol.OutputValue:
                    if ((OptimizationLevel & OptimizationLevel.Level1) >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
                    {
                        if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
                        {
                            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                            symbolRepeated = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lastSymbol = symbol;
                            symbolRepeated++;
                        }
                    }

                    symbolRepeated = 0;
                    Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                    break;
                case TokenSymbol.Decrement:
                case TokenSymbol.Increment:
                case TokenSymbol.MoveLeft:
                case TokenSymbol.MoveRight:
                    if ((OptimizationLevel & OptimizationLevel.Level1) >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
                    {
                        if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
                        {
                            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                            symbolRepeated = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lastSymbol = symbol;
                            symbolRepeated++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        symbolRepeated = 1;
                        Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
                    }
                    break;
            }

            lastSymbol = symbol;
        }
    }

    private string[] SymbolToLines(TokenSymbol symbol, int repeated, int indentLevels)
    {
        switch (symbol)
        {
            case TokenSymbol.Decrement:
                if (repeated == 1)
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}buffer[index]--;" };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}buffer[index] -= {repeated};" };
                }
            case TokenSymbol.Increment:
                if (repeated == 1)
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}buffer[index]++;" };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}buffer[index] += {repeated};" };
                }
            case TokenSymbol.InputCharacter:
                return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}buffer[index] = ReadChar();" };
            case TokenSymbol.LoopBegin:
                return new[] { "", $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}while (buffer[index] != 0)", $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}{{" };
            case TokenSymbol.LoopEnd:
                return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}}}", "" };
            case TokenSymbol.MoveLeft:
                if (repeated == 1)
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}index--;" };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}index -= {repeated};" };
                }
            case TokenSymbol.MoveRight:
                if (repeated == 1)
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}index++;" };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}index += {repeated};" };
                }
            case TokenSymbol.OutputValue:
                return new[] { $"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);" };
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static string GetIndents(int levels) => new string(' ', levels * 4);
}
```

This interprets the Brainfuck to it's appropriate lines.

The `Transpiler`:

```
public class Transpiler
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    public string SourceFile { get; set; }
    public string ProgrammeName { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFile { get; set; }
    public string ExecutableFile { get; set; }
    public int BufferSize { get; set; }
    public string DotNetVersion { get; set; }
    public OptimizationLevel OptimizationLevel { get; set; }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> _dotNetFolders = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "2.0", "v2.0.50727" }, { "3.5", "v3.5" }, { "4.0", "v4.0.30319" } };

    public Transpiler(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public void AcquireInput(IPrompt prompt)
    {
        SourceFile = AddExtension(prompt.Prompt<string>("Enter the source filename (.bf)", PromptOptions.Required, validationMethod: x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)), ".bf");
        ProgrammeName = SourceFile.Substring(0, SourceFile.LastIndexOf('.'));
        DestinationFile = AddExtension(prompt.Prompt("Enter the destination filename (.cs)", PromptOptions.Optional, ProgrammeName + ".cs", validationMethod: x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)), ".cs");
        ExecutableFile = AddExtension(prompt.Prompt("Enter the destination executable (.exe)", PromptOptions.Optional, ProgrammeName + ".exe", validationMethod: x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)), ".exe");
        BufferSize = prompt.Prompt("Enter buffer size", PromptOptions.Optional, 2048);
        DotNetVersion = prompt.Prompt("Enter .NET version to compile with", PromptOptions.Optional, "4.0", "Version can be any of: 2.0, 3.5, 4.0", x => _dotNetFolders.ContainsKey(x));
    }

    private static string AddExtension(string data, string extension)
    {
        if (data.IndexOf('.') == -1)
        {
            data += extension;
        }

        return data;
    }

    public string LoadBrainfuckCode(string filename) => File.ReadAllText(filename);

    public void Transpile()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SourceFile)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProgrammeName)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DestinationFile)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ExecutableFile)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DotNetVersion)
            || BufferSize <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The values for {nameof(SourceFile)}, {nameof(ProgrammeName)}, {nameof(DestinationFile)}, {nameof(ExecutableFile)}, {nameof(DotNetVersion)} cannot be null or whitespace, and {nameof(BufferSize)} cannot be zero or negative. Did you forget to call {nameof(AcquireInput)}?");
        }

        // Now that that's over.
        var interpreter = new Interpreter();
        interpreter.OptimizationLevel = OptimizationLevel;

        var brainfuck = LoadBrainfuckCode(SourceFile);

        interpreter.Interpret(brainfuck);

        var template = AcquireTemplate("CompiledTemplate.cs");

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var line in interpreter.Lines)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }

        var result = template;
        result = result.Replace("BufferSize", BufferSize.ToString());
        result = result.Replace("BrainfuckCode;", sb.ToString().TrimStart());

        WriteToCsFile(DestinationFile, result);
        CompileCsFile(_dotNetFolders[DotNetVersion], DestinationFile, ExecutableFile);
    }

    public void WriteToCsFile(string filename, string data)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }

    public string AcquireTemplate(string filename) => File.ReadAllText(filename);

    public void CompileCsFile(string dotNetPath, string sourceFile, string executableFile)
    {
        Logger.LogImportant($"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\{dotNetPath}\\csc.exe /t:exe /out:\"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\{executableFile}\" \"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\{sourceFile}\"");
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo($@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{dotNetPath}\csc.exe", $"/t:exe /out:\"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\{executableFile}\" \"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\{sourceFile}\"");
        var process = Process.Start(info);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

This does the heavy-lifting of the compiler to call the appropriate methods to convert the Brainfuck to C#.

Lastly, the new `Program`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = new ConsoleLogger(LoggingType.All);
        var transpiler = new Transpiler.Transpiler(logger);
        transpiler.OptimizationLevel = Transpiler.OptimizationLevel.Level1;
        var prompter = new ConsolePrompt(logger);
        transpiler.AcquireInput(prompter);
        transpiler.Transpile();

        Process.Start(transpiler.ExecutableFile);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter key to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Pretty self-explanatory.

Major notes: The project is no longer one huge `Program.cs`, but features a somewhat object-oriented approach to the Brainfuck interpretation and compilation.

Example `HelloWorld.bf`:

> ```
> [ This program prints "Hello World!" and a newline to the screen, its
>   length is 106 active command characters. [It is not the shortest.]
>
>  This loop is a "comment loop", a simple way of adding a comment
>   to a BF program such that you don't have to worry about any command
>   characters. Any ".", ",", "+", "-", "<" and ">" characters are simply
>   ignored, the "[" and "]" characters just have to be balanced. This
>   loop and the commands it contains are ignored because the current cell
>   defaults to a value of 0; the 0 value causes this loop to be skipped.
> ]
> +++++ +++               Set Cell #0 to 8
> [
>     >++++               Add 4 to Cell #1; this will always set Cell #1 to 4
>     [                   as the cell will be cleared by the loop
>         >++             Add 2 to Cell #2
>         >+++            Add 3 to Cell #3
>         >+++            Add 3 to Cell #4
>         >+              Add 1 to Cell #5
>         <<<<-           Decrement the loop counter in Cell #1
>     ]                   Loop till Cell #1 is zero; number of iterations is 4
>     >+                  Add 1 to Cell #2
>     >+                  Add 1 to Cell #3
>     >-                  Subtract 1 from Cell #4
>     >>+                 Add 1 to Cell #6
>     [<]                 Move back to the first zero cell you find; this will
>                         be Cell #1 which was cleared by the previous loop
>     <-                  Decrement the loop Counter in Cell #0
> ]                       Loop till Cell #0 is zero; number of iterations is 8
>
> The result of this is:
> Cell No :   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
> Contents:   0   0  72 104  88  32   8
> Pointer :   ^
>
> >>.                     Cell #2 has value 72 which is 'H'
> >---.                   Subtract 3 from Cell #3 to get 101 which is 'e'
> +++++++..+++.           Likewise for 'llo' from Cell #3
> >>.                     Cell #5 is 32 for the space
> <-.                     Subtract 1 from Cell #4 for 87 to give a 'W'
> <.                      Cell #3 was set to 'o' from the end of 'Hello'
> +++.------.--------.    Cell #3 for 'rl' and 'd'
> >>+.                    Add 1 to Cell #5 gives us an exclamation point
> >++.                    And finally a newline from Cell #6
> ```

Converts to:

> ```
> using System;
>
> namespace Brainfuck_Interpreter
> {
>     class CompiledTemplate
>     {
>         static byte ReadChar()
>         {
>             return (byte)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
>         }
>
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
>             int index = 0;
>
>             while (buffer[index] != 0)
>             {
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>                 Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>
>                 while (buffer[index] != 0)
>                 {
>                     Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>                 }
>
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>                 Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>                 Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>                 buffer[index]++;
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>                 buffer[index]--;
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>                 index--;
>                 index++;
>                 buffer[index] = ReadChar();
>
>                 while (buffer[index] != 0)
>                 {
>                 }
>
>                 Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>                 Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             }
>
>             buffer[index] += 8;
>
>             while (buffer[index] != 0)
>             {
>                 index++;
>                 buffer[index] += 4;
>
>                 while (buffer[index] != 0)
>                 {
>                     index++;
>                     buffer[index] += 2;
>                     index++;
>                     buffer[index] += 3;
>                     index++;
>                     buffer[index] += 3;
>                     index++;
>                     buffer[index]++;
>                     index -= 4;
>                     buffer[index]--;
>                 }
>
>                 index++;
>                 buffer[index]++;
>                 index++;
>                 buffer[index]++;
>                 index++;
>                 buffer[index]--;
>                 index += 2;
>                 buffer[index]++;
>
>                 while (buffer[index] != 0)
>                 {
>                     index--;
>                 }
>
>                 index--;
>                 buffer[index]--;
>             }
>
>             index += 2;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             index++;
>             buffer[index] -= 3;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             buffer[index] += 7;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             buffer[index] += 3;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             index += 2;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             index--;
>             buffer[index]--;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             index--;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             buffer[index] += 3;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             buffer[index] -= 6;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             buffer[index] -= 8;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             index += 2;
>             buffer[index]++;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>             index++;
>             buffer[index] += 2;
>             Console.Write((char)buffer[index]);
>
>
>             Console.WriteLine("Program terminated successfully...");
>             Console.ReadLine();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> if ((OptimizationLevel & OptimizationLevel.Level1) >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
> {
>     if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
>     {
>         Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
>         symbolRepeated = 0;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         lastSymbol = symbol;
>         symbolRepeated++;
>     }
> }
> ```

These lines are duplicated* 5 times in `void Interpret(string)`: once in every single `case` block.. not ideal.

Start by copying it again a 6th time, here:

```
foreach (var symbol in _symbols)
{
    if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
    {

    }

    switch (symbol)
    {
        ...
```

Now remove it from every single case block, except the last one* - and then turn this:

> ```
> if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
> ```

Into this:

```
if (lastSymbol != symbol && lastSymbol != TokenSymbol.None 
       && (lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Decrement 
        || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.Increment 
        || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveLeft 
        || lastSymbol == TokenSymbol.MoveRight))
```

Ah, *now* we can read it! Or can we? What's it saying anyway? What do the `Decrement`, `Increment`, `MoveLeft` and `MoveRight` symbols have in common?

Could we say that they're the instructions you consider *optimizable*?

```
private static readonly TokenSymbol[] OptimizableInstructions = 
{
    TokenSymbol.Decrement,
    TokenSymbol.Increment,
    TokenSymbol.MoveLeft,
    TokenSymbol.MoveRight
};
```

And that condition is verifying what exactly, whether the *current* symbol ends a sequence of repeating *previous symbol*?

```
private static bool IsRepeatedSymbolSequenceEnding(TokenSymbol previous, TokenSymbol current) 
        => previous != current 
        && previous != TokenSymbol.None 
        && OptimizableInstructions.Contains(previous);
```

That little static function is just enough abstraction to know what's going on without being bothered with the whole 12-operator logic:

```
if (IsRepeatedSymbolSequenceEnding(lastSymbol, symbol))
{
    Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, symbolRepeated, indents));
    symbolRepeated = 0;
}
else
{
    lastSymbol = symbol;
    symbolRepeated++;
}
```

Not sure I like the naming - I mean, `IsRepeatedSymbolSequenceEnding` is kinda awful, but I'm thinking more of `lastSymbol` versus `symbolRepeated` - "last symbol" reads well. "repeated symbol" would read better than `symbolRepeated`.. but the variable is an `int` and is actually counting *repetitions* - wouldn't `repetitions` be a much better name for it?

Anyway, I skipped something:

> ```
> if ((OptimizationLevel & OptimizationLevel.Level1) >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
> ```

Why the bitwise operation on a non-flag enum here? What's wrong with simplicity here?

```
if (OptimizationLevel >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
```

Per [C# spec. 7.9.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664726(v=vs.71).aspx), enum comparison operators operate like their underlying type:

> *In other words, the enumeration type comparison operators simply compare the underlying integral values of the two operands.*

KISS dude.

*The last block is *slightly* different.

---

So, that last block.

> ```
> case TokenSymbol.Decrement:
> case TokenSymbol.Increment:
> case TokenSymbol.MoveLeft:
> case TokenSymbol.MoveRight:
> ```

Where have I seen those...

Ah, yes!

```
private static readonly TokenSymbol[] OptimizableInstructions = 
{
    TokenSymbol.Decrement,
    TokenSymbol.Increment,
    TokenSymbol.MoveLeft,
    TokenSymbol.MoveRight
};
```

I think you could turn that `foreach` loop into this then:

```
foreach (var symbol in _symbols)
{
    if (OptimizationLevel >= OptimizationLevel.Level1)
    {
        var isOptimizableSymbol = OptimizableInstructions.Contains(symbol);
        if (IsRepeatedSymbolSequenceEnding(lastSymbol, symbol))
        {
            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(lastSymbol, repetitions, indents));
            repetitions = isOptimizableSymbol ? 1 : 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isOptimizableSymbol)
            {
                repetitions++;
            }
            else
            {
                repetitions = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    switch (symbol)
    {
        case TokenSymbol.LoopBegin:
            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, repetitions, indents));
            indents += 1;
            break;

        case TokenSymbol.LoopEnd:
            indents -= 1;
            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, repetitions, indents));
            break;

        case TokenSymbol.InputCharacter:
        case TokenSymbol.OutputValue:
            Lines.AddRange(SymbolToLines(symbol, repetitions, indents));
            break;
    }

    lastSymbol = symbol;
}
```

Notice `lastSymbol = symbol` appears once, at the end of the loop, and `symbolRepeated` doesn't need to be handled in the individual `case` blocks... which don't need a block for the `OptimizableInstructions` - and input/output can share the same `case` block.

I'm sure it could be further simplified - I don't like that nested `if` I've given you there... but it's already a bit better than it was, I think. Right?

Comment: Great stuff! I was having issues figuring out how I could abstract away that massive `if` block, and this handles it. :)

Answer (score 5):

[MatsMug's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111674/16369) is very good. However, I would "Keep It Even Simpler" with the following improvements:

---

You created the `TokenSymbol` enum... but why? You already have a perfectly good enumeration: `+ - < > [ ] , .`. If you use these character values as the enumerators, then you can get rid of the entire `Tokenize` function.

---

You have this concept of a repeated `TokenSymbol` (for example, "`+` repeated 3 times"), but you haven't encapsulated this concept into a single entity. How about introducing something like this?

```
struct RepeatedToken {
    public char token;
    public int repetitions;
}

List<RepeatedToken> Tokenize(string brainfuck) { ... }
```

Then you can generate code for a `RepeatedToken` all in one go.

```
switch (rt.token) {
    case '>':
        Lines.Append($"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}index += {rt.repetitions};");
    case '<':
        Lines.Append($"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}index -= {rt.repetitions};");
    case '[':
        for (int i=0; i < reptok.repetitions; ++i) {
            Lines.Append($"{GetIndents(indentLevels)}while (buffer[index] != 0) {");
            indentLevels += 1;
        }
    ...
```

and so on.

---

Once you've got this working (with about half the number of lines you have right now), the next *complication* I'd think of adding would be a special case optimization for `[-]` (a.k.a. `buffer[index] = 0;`). But this sequence of tokens doesn't fit into the `RepeatedToken` paradigm we were just developing! You'll have to generalize again. Perhaps what we mean when we say `RepeatedToken` is really more like [`Opcode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) — it could be "increment by N" (an opcode taking an operand), or "set current location to zero" (our new case), or "start a loop" (note: not "start N loops"; let's back off from the idea that *everything* has to be `Repeated`).

So now you've got the basic outline of a compiler: it'll take the input string, chunk it up into `Opcode`s according to the [maximal munch rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch), and then pretty-print each of those `Opcode`s to the output string.

---

You would also benefit from designing a little class to manage your pretty-print indentation, so you can stop writing so many curly braces and dollar signs. I would imagine something like this:

```
PrettyPrinter.Print("while (buffer[index] != 0) {");
PrettyPrinter.Indent();
PrettyPrinter.Print("index += 1;");
PrettyPrinter.Outdent();
PrettyPrinter.Print("}");
```

---

As for "optimization levels", that's probably [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) ...levels. :)  However, if you do want to implement optimization levels, I **strongly** advise that the best practice in this department is not to hard-code tests like "if OptimizationLevel > 1 ..." into the actual code generator. What you should do instead is:

Implement a set of (ideally orthogonal) flags, for example

```
bool SquashRepetitions;
bool OptimizeSetToZero;
bool PrettyPrintWithIndentation;
...
```

Hard-code tests of *these* flags into your code-generator.

Then, at the very topmost level of your program, where you parse the command-line options passed in by the user (or however your user is going to specify that he wants `-O0` versus `-O1`), write something like this:

```
SquashRepetitions = (OptimizationLevel >= 1);
OptimizeSetToZero = (OptimizationLevel >= 2);
PrettyPrintWithIndentation = (OptimizationLevel == 0);
...
```

(The exact method of doing this — whether you use a `switch` on `OptimizationLevel`, or a nest of `if`s, or a bunch of independent `if`s, or a bunch of independent assignments as shown here — is a matter of taste. Doesn't matter. The important point is that you are setting the backend's low-level flags based on the high-level optimization strategy, not scattering high-level strategy decisions throughout the backend.

For bonus points, you could replace that bunch of `bool` variables with a single `bool` *array* indexed by an enumeration, and then use `Enum.Parse()` to support command-line switches such as `/GSquashRepetitions`, `/GOptimizeSetToZero`, etc.

Comment: I will admit that the `TokenSymbol` seems redundant, but I forget what the actual characters mean so it's nice to have an enum to tell me what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a look at `OptimizationLevel` enum and your description:

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Determines how the <see cref="Interpreter"/> will optimize Brainfuck code.
> /// </summary>
> public enum OptimizationLevel
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Do not apply any optimizations.
>     /// </summary>
>     None,
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Apply first level optimizations (combining sequences of increment/decrement characters into one increment/decrement per sequence).
>     /// </summary>
>     Level1,
> }
> ```
>
> This is self-explanatory. It represents the (currently two) possible optimization levels of BrainfuckSharp. Specifying None will not optimize the code, specifying Level1 will apply basic optimizations.

Well I don't think this is as self-explanatory as it could be. I see 3 terms to be used for that `OptimizationLevel` which isn't `None`.

We have the name `Level1`, the `summary` states `Apply first level optimizations` and in your description you talk about `basic optimizations`. Which of these should it be ? I guess this will just depend wether you will extend this some more.

By the way, I guess you had some more values in that enum... having a `,` after `Level1` is a clear indicator ;-).

---

IMO the `_validTokens` should be initialized in the constructor using the `Keys` of the `_tokenMap` dictionary. In this way you need, for any future changes (maybe BrainFuck 4.0), only need to change that dictionary.

```
public Interpreter() 
{
    _validTokens = _tokenMap.Keys.ToList();
}
```

---

The `WriteToFile()` method can be optimized by using `string.Jouin()` like so

```
public void WriteToFile(string filename)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,Lines));
    }
}
```

---

Most of the remaining is already reviewed by @MatsMug.

Comment: Having a trailing comma does not necessarily mean that there are, or will be, new enum entries. I often use trailing commas myself just to make the version control diffs cleaner (I hate it when a line is considered changed just to add a comma)